# matlab error, attempt to reference field of non structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab

All the references to this error I could find searching online were completely inapplicable to my situation, they were dealing with some kind of variables involving dots, like `a.b` (structures in other words), whereas I am strictly using arrays. Nothing involves a dot, nor does my code ask about it.

Ok, I have this GINORMOUS array called `tier2comparatorconnectionpoints`. It is a 4-D array of size 400×10×20×10. Consider `tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(counter,counter2,counter3,counter4)`.

- `counter` is a number `1` to `400`,
- `counter2` is a number `1` to `numchromosomes(counter)`, and `numchromosomes(counter1)` is bound to `10`,
- `counter3` is a number `1` to `tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, which is in turn bounded to `20`.
- `counter4` is a number `1` to `tier2inputspercomparator(counter,counter2,counter3)`, which is bounded to `10`.

Now, so that I don't run out of RAM, I have `tier2comparatorconnectionpoints` as type `int8`, and UNFORTUNATELY at some point in my horrendous amount of code, I forgot to cast it to a `double` when I'm doing math with it, and a rounding error involved with multiplying it with a `rand` ends up with `tier2comparatorconnectionpoints` for some values of its `4` inputs exceeding what it's allowed to be.

The values it's allowed to have are 1 through `tier1numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, which is bounded to `40`, `41` through `40+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, with `tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)` being bounded to `20`, and `61` through `60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, thus it's not allowed to be more than `80` since `tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)` is bounded to `20` and it's not allowed to be more than `60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, but it's also not allowed to be less than `40` but more than `tier1numcomparators(counter,counter2)` and it's not allowed to be less than `60` but more than `40+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`. I became aware of the problem because it was being set to `81` somewhere.

This is an evolutionary simulation by the way, it's natural selection on simulated organisms. I need to hunt down the part of the code that is allowing the values of `tier2comparatorconnectionpoints` to exceed what it's allowed to be. But that is a separate problem.

A temporary fix of my data, just so that it at least is made to conform to its allowed values, is to set anything that is greater than `tier1numcomparators(counter,counter2)` but less than `40` to `tier1numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, to set anything that is greater than `40+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)` but less than `60` to `40+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, and to set anything that is greater than `60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)` to `60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`. I first found this problem because it was being set to `81`, so it didn't just exceed `60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)`, it exceeded `60+20`, with `tier2numcomparators` being bounded to `20`.

I hope this isn't all too-much-information, but I felt it might be necessary to get you to understand just what sort of variables these are.

So in my attempts to at least turn the data into valid data, I did the following:

```
for counter=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,1)
 for counter2=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,2)
  for counter3=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,3)
   for counter4=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,4)
    if tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(counter,counter2,counter3,counter4)>60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)
     tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(counter,counter2,counter3,counter4)=60+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2);
    end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

And that worked just fine. And then:

```
for counter=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,1)
 for counter2=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,2)
  for counter3=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,3)
   for counter4=1:size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints,4)
    if tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(counter,counter2,counter3,counter4)>40+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2)
     if tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(counter,counter2,counter3,counter4)<60
      tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(counter,counter2,counter3,counter4)=40+tier2numcomparators(counter,counter2);
     end
    end
   end
  end
 end
end
```

And that's where it said "Attempt to reference field of non-structure array".

Comment: You write like you should go outside and play soccer for a couple of hours...

Comment: Your array is not that big. It would be a tiny medical image dataset. 
400*10*20*10* (8bytes/double) / (2^20 bytes/MB) = 6.1MB. I think you have enough RAM.

Answer (score 5):

TBH it sounds like maybe you've made a typo and put a `.` in somewhere? Otherwise please post the entire error as maybe it's happening in a different function or something.

Either way you don't need all those for loops, it's simpler and usually quicker to do this (and should bypass your error):

First [replicate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) your `tier2numcomparators` matrix so that it has the same dimension sizes as `tier2comparatorconnectionpoints`

```
T = repmat(tier2numcomparators + 40, 1, 1, size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints, 3), size(tier2comparatorconnectionpoints, 4));
```

Now in one shot you can create a logical matrix of which elements meet your criteria:

```
ind = tier2comparatorconnectionpoints > T | tier2comparatorconnectionpoints < 60;
```

Finally employ [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) to set your desired elements:

```
tier2comparatorconnectionpoints(ind) = T(ind);
```

You can play around with `bsxfun` instead of `repmat` if this is slow or takes too much memory

Comment: Ok, I am totally reinstalling matlab now. It was totally fubar, after I posted this it was coming up with some kind of visualbasic or visualc error when Matlab started up. So there you have it. Thanks for looking at my situation.

Comment: As for your suggestion, I don't know how to do that, or even what its operating principles are, I can only do what I know how to do. I'm not a very good programmer, I have a limited vocabulary of tools.

Comment: @zortharg In Matlab you can apply most operation to entire matrices. But they have to be the same size. I'll add an explanation of how to use my code